# Is transaction scope available in Entity framework 6.0

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6

Entity framework 6.0 articles shows only "UseTransaction" and "BeginTransaction". Is transaction scope still available in Entity framework 6.0. If yes, how to use it and which dll to include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes its available and you can use System.Transactions dll file.

check this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843)